# Show username afer killing a Confluence calendar thread

Tags: calendar, confluence, java-melody

There are a number of known issues with Confluence calendars. When a Confluence administrator needs to kill a Team Calendars thread it can be useful to know which user calendar was affected so the problem can be investigated.

After killing a calendar thread in Confluence via JavaMelody how can the username of the affected user be found?

Answer (score 0):

1. Calendar threads can be viewed in [JavaMelody](https://code.google.com/archive/p/javamelody/).
2. To kill a calendar thread, usually when locked or not responding, click the red dot to the right hand side of the thread name in the **Current requests** field.
3. An error message is thrown to the atlassian-confluence.log referencing **mycalendar.action** which has the username of the affected user on the same line

   ```
   cat /opt/wiki/logs/atlassian-confluence.lo* | ggrep -b1  "mycalendar.action" | egrep -v "RuntimeException" | ggrep -a1 date '+%m-%d'
   ```

This shows all lines in the log for which correspond to the mycalendar.action thread kills for the current day.